# Hide table td if contain exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coding-style

I need to hide all my table td's if they contain only the sign "%".

I have two types of results:

```
<td>%</td>
<td>1%</td>
```

I want to hide all td's who have only the %. Those who have 1% or 2% or any other number infront of % must remain visible.

I made a js but its hiding all the td's(i understand perfectly why: because i used **:contains** and if the td contain the % then it will be hidden):

```
if (jQuery('#results table tbody tr td:contains("%")').length > 0) {
    jQuery("#results table tbody tr td").hide();
}
```

I need to know how to know how to do this.
Thank you

Comment: Your jQuery is wrong, and your idea of why it's wrong is also wrong. You've written two completely separate jQuery selectors. The one inside the `if` has nothing to do with the one in the `if` condition. You're selecting different elements both times. Inside the `if`, you need to reference the results found by the *first* `jQuery(...)`, by storing them in a variable or by iterating over them with `each`/`filter`/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("#results table tbody tr td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "%";
}).parent().hide();
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6fFL/) to demonstrate.

Comment: I stand correct, it does return a jQuery object. This would be the better solution.

Comment: @Stan Just put a `.parent()` call in before the `.hide()`

Comment: @RGraham Thank you so much. Its perfect now.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `each` like

```
$('#results table tbody tr td').each(function(){
     if($(this).text() == "%") {
         $(this).hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$('#results table tbody tr td').each(function(){
     if($(this).text().indexOf('%')!=-1)
     {
         $(this).hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: That will hide every `<td>` that contains `%` anywhere inside it. Including the `<td>%1</td>` that he doesn't want to hide.